# stylelint gives error "Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null" when introducing stylelint-config-standard-scss

Tags: angular, sass, stylelint

I'm at at a bit of a loss today. I wanted to add Stylelint to my Angular project, so I ran

`npm install stylelint stylelint-config-standard --save-dev`

to install stylelint and the standard config plug in. I then created a `.stylelintrc` file and added the follow code to it:

```
{
  "extends": ["stylelint-config-standard"],
  "rules": {
    "rule-empty-line-before": "always",
    "comment-empty-line-before": "always"
  }
}
```

When running the following command `npx stylelint \"src/app/**/*.{css,scss}\"` from the terminal I noticed all worked well but as I am using scss in my Angular project I saw some errors. To prevent these scss based errors I decided to introduce the `stylelint-config-standard-scss` plugin. I installed this using npm then updated the code in my `.stylelintrc` file to the following:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "stylelint-config-standard",
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "rule-empty-line-before": "always",
    "comment-empty-line-before": "always"
  }
}
```

Now when I run the command `npx stylelint \"src/app/**/*.{css,scss}\"` I get the following error!

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myuser/my-project/node_modules/postcss-scss/lib/nested-declaration.js:3:33)
    at Module._compile (/Users/myuser/my-project/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (/Users/myuser/my-project/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myuser/my-project/node_modules/postcss-scss/lib/scss-parser.js:4:25)
    at Module._compile (/Users/myuser/my-project/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
```

I can't understand why this is happening. The `stylelint-config-standard-scss` plugin is downloaded and in my `node_modules` folder. There isn't a syntax error in my `.stylelintrc` file. My node version is good (v14.18.1), I even uninstalled and reinstalled all npm packages but I get the same error? Has anyone else had this problem and was able to resolve it?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had this problem, I managed to fix this by adding postcss as a dev dependency in the package.json file, for example:

```
"devDependencies": {
   "postcss": "^8.4.13"
}
```

Comment: Now I am stuck with PostCSS warnings saying it does nothing until I fix some postCSS config file :(

This fixed it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73247614/6434747

Answer (score 0):

I find a [solution](https://github.com/stylelint-scss/stylelint-config-standard-scss/issues/5#issuecomment-1000025410) from github issue thread after google. You only need to do is to install postcss@8 with npm install.