# Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null in Nuxt2

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js

Am getting a strange error which I haven't been able to figure out, in my vue component, whenever I use `<style lang="scss">` I get the error `Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null`, but all other types (i.e. `sass`, `less`) do not throw that error, complete code for the style tag is

```
<style lang="scss">
/* stylelint-disable-next-line selector-class-pattern */
.ProseMirror {
  p {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
</style>
```

Am using **Nuxt2** and I have installed `"sass": "^1.54.7"` and `"sass-loader": "^10.3.1"`, all my other separate `.scss` files work fine, exception is when I include style tag with scss lang in a vue component, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After continuing my search, I came across this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72273009/3187105, which the solution seemed to have worked in my case. Adding a `postcss` as a dev dependency seemed to be the solution.